# Printing in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, printing, ms-office

At work, I've been tasked with fixing a horrible spreadsheet they have been using for many years. What I'm looking for is a solution to allow me to print (in duplex, some time after the basic program is working) the same spreadsheet, but update the date before printing the next one. If this project was in C or C++ I could handle it but using the Excel sheet is making it impossible for me. I've been searching for days upon end and can't get anything to work. I do not care what specific language, I just don't know anything about MS office programming. Any suggestions?

Example:
Spreadsheet is called "LC" in workbook LCWB.XLS
in pseudocode I'm looking for:

A button or input that will allow me to select 10 12 14 weeks, and store that number * 7 to provide days in a variable we will call X.

There will also be the "beginning date" stored in a cell "A1"

The date is supplied to the program to update the date at every iteration, until there are 70 pages with consecutive dates on them.

Then a loop

while count <= X
  print excel worksheet LC
  update "date cell"="date cell" + 1

Does not need to save anything, I hope this makes sense, if not, I will upload part of the actual sheet. I'd really like to figure this out in part on my own to learn, but I'm so confused. 
Like I previously mentioned, the language doesn't matter. VBA in Excel, VB, VC#... The computer running this has Win XP SP3 and Office 2007.

Comment: I would recommend VBA for such a simple task. Would really help if you included a sample workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you needing to print the sheet out if nothing on the sheet changes but the dates?

I'm a print provider and would refer to this as a variable data printing project. Personally (knowing design software) I would put all the dates into a CSV file and then put the rest of the documents content in InDesign. Alternatively you may be able to use M$ Word's mail merge feature... Anyhow have a field in the document  (like a form letter) that pulls the dates from the CSV file. Word or InDesign will generate the multi-page file for you to print with the dates inserted where that field was.

Comment: thanks, the data is all in excel, using the mail merge did do the trick. I am re writing the book in its entirety to avoid the pitfalls of what I have. I will update this older thread with the code I got to make it work